# SharePoint 2013 - Imageslider / image are not ajusting to web part zone (width)

Tags: web-part, css, web-part-zone, branding

No. Adjust height to fit zone. - Do not work for images / imageslider.

Problem:
I've inserted imageslider into a web part, and using the property "no. Adjust height to fit zone". But the images do not resize correctly in each web part. Each picture takes more space than what I set to the current zone.

PageLayout

```
              <td class="middleWebPartZoneTD2 fullWidth wpTitleBorderBox greyTitleWebPart" valign="top" style="padding: 0">
                <table class="tableTRfullWidth" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="zone1 middleImageSlider" Width="60%" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" height="100%">
                            <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="ImageSlider" ID="middleImageSlider" FrameType="TitleBarOnly">
                                <ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
                            </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
                        </td>
                        <td class="zone2 middleImages" Width="35%" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" height="100%">
                            <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="MiddleImages" ID="middleImages" FrameType="TitleBarOnly">
                                <ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
                            </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

I've tried to set width directly to the web part..

Comment: What ImageSlider are we talking about, content search webpart  display template ?

Comment: No the standard one..

Comment: I wasn't aware of another image slider option in SP 2013 other than display templates on search related WP's. Of these  implementations, I know that they do not care about your webpart zone's width/height. In a similar situation I had to resize them in the display template itself.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not likely the answer that everyone would like to use, resize the images themselves to the appropriate size before uploading . Making SP do the work increases overhead and can cause lag in addition to issues with correct sizing and appearance on the site.
Relying on a program to make changes on the fly is not a good idea. It is far better both from a SA perspective and a UX perspective to make sure your images are correctly sized to begin with.